# Python priniting strings with spaces between each characters

Tags: python, powershell

I have this simple python script:

```
with open("records.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

`records.cvs` contains many lines like the following.

> ,0.055,,,,109.889456433,119.043269058,128.455997141,,,,-0.607526459169,-1.28987216622,-1.36255539212,-0.0783128865694,-0.0745923352488,-0.0722692557059,0.325311331044,0.61140286319,0.0509661014105,0.719556483734

However, our script above prints the following output with spaces between characters.

> ■, 0 . 0 5 5 , , , , 1 0 9 . 8 8 9 4 5 6 4 3 3 , 1 1 9 . 0 4 3 2 6 9 0 5 8 , 1 2 8 . 4 5 5 9 9 7 1 4 1 , , , , - 0 . 6 0 7 5 2 6 4 5 9 1 6 9 , - 1 . 2 8 9 8 7 2 1 6 6 2 2 , - 1 .
>   3 6 2 5 5 5 3 9 2 1 2 , - 0 . 0 7 8 3 1 2 8 8 6 5 6 9 4 , - 0 . 0 7 4 5 9 2 3 3 5 2 4 8 8 , - 0 . 0 7 2 2 6 9 2 5 5 7 0 5 9 , 0 . 3 2 5 3 1 1 3 3 1 0 4 4 , 0 . 6 1 1 4 0 2 8 6 3 1
>     , 0 . 0 5 0 9 6 6 1 0 1 4 1 0 5 , 0 . 7 1 9 5 5 6 4 8 3 7 3 4

Why does the output have spaces and how can we remove them.

Comment: `print line,` instead of `print line`?

Comment: Can not reproduce. It prints blank lines between lines, but no spaces between characters. What is that funny square symbol? Maybe it's an encoding problem?

Comment: @segfolt `print line,` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @tobias_k you got it right. It seems the encoding was set to `Little Endian`. Make your comment an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @RandomDownvoter care to explain the down-vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not reproduce your results. I've created a file with a number of lines as the one in your example, but while it prints blank lines between lines (one for the line end, and one for the `print`), there are no spaces between characters.

Note that funny square symbol at the beginning of your printed line? It might be a problem with the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean to use `csv.reader`:

```
import csv

with open("records.csv", "r") as f:
    csvin = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvin:
        print line
```

`line` will then be a list of the columns from each row of the CSV file - and you work with that as you will (maybe convert each to integer/float where possible for instance).

Try filtering out none printable characters first...

`import re` and after your `with statement`, change to:

```
lines = (re.sub('[^-0-9.,]', '', line) for line in f)
csvin = csv.reader(lines)
```

Comment: I have tried this before and I ran into the error `_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte` but I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @andre Might be worth trying to filter out stuff that isn't `-`, `.` or a `,` or a `digit` and just use those...

Comment: Your initial solution works perfectly fine now that I have the right encoding.